# How can I prove they are congruent?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

if $m$ is an integer and $\gcd(m,3)=1$，prove that $m^7\equiv m \pmod {63}
$.
I try using Fermat's Little Theorem,but it doesn't work.
Please help me.

Comment: Please write more informative titles when you ask a question ([how to ask](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)). This title is quite ambiguous and it could be about geometry. Remember that other users cannot see the tags before clicking on the question.

Comment: Sure,I will try to improve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $\varphi(9)=6$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler Totient Function, and $(m,3)=1$:
$$m^7\equiv m\mod 9$$
By FLT, we also have:
$$m^7\equiv m\mod 7$$
Then using Chinese Remainder Theorem:
$$m^7\equiv m\mod 63$$

Comment: Oh，Thank you very much！

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $63=9*7$. Use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Thank you, what you mentioned is the content of our next chapter, I will preview it and have a try.